# Three.js: Keeping child below parent mesh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, three.js, 3d

I'm trying to create a table in Three.js but the legs of the table goes through the parent.
[image: Current Result]

**Parent Mesh:**

```
    const boxWidth = 2; const boxHeight = 0.1; const boxDepth = 1;
    const tableBoardGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const customPicture = textureLoader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/resources/images/compressed-but-large-wood-texture.jpg')
    const tableBoardMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: customPicture})
    const tableBoard = new THREE.Mesh(tableBoardGeometry, tableBoardMaterial)
    tableBoard.position.set(0, 0, 0)
```

**SubMesh (The legs of the table)**

```
   const tableLegsGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.05, 1, 0.05);
   const tableLegsMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(({map: customPicture}))
   const tableLeg1 = new THREE.Mesh(tableLegsGeometry, tableLegsMaterial)
   const tableLeg2 = new THREE.Mesh(tableLegsGeometry, tableLegsMaterial)
   const tableLeg3 = new THREE.Mesh(tableLegsGeometry, tableLegsMaterial)
   const tableLeg4 = new THREE.Mesh(tableLegsGeometry, tableLegsMaterial)
   tableLeg1.position.set(0.9, 0, -0.4)
   tableLeg2.position.set(-0.9, 0, -0.4)
   tableLeg3.position.set(-0.9, 0, 0.4)
   tableLeg4.position.set(0.9, 0, 0.4)
```

**The relation between the two**

```
    const group = new THREE.Group();
    tableBoard.add(tableLeg1, tableLeg2, tableLeg3, tableLeg4);
    scene.add(tableBoard);
```

How do i make the legs of the table always stay below the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`THREE.BoxGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry) creates a symmetric box with a width, height and depth, where the center of the box is at (0, 0, 0).

If the plate of the table should be on top of the legs, then you've to change the y position of the plate, by the half height of the leg and the half height of the plate (1.0/2 + 0.1/2 = 0.55):

```js
const boxWidth = 2; const boxHeight = 0.1; const boxDepth = 1;
const tableBoardGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);
// ...
const tableBoard = new THREE.Mesh(tableBoardGeometry, tableBoardMaterial);
tableBoard.position.set(0, 0.55, 0);
```

If you want that the bottom of the legs is at 0.0, then you've to "lift up" the legs by 0.5 and the palte by 1.05:

```js
const tableBoard = new THREE.Mesh(tableBoardGeometry, tableBoardMaterial)
tableBoard.position.set(0, 1.05, 0)
```

```js
const tableLegsGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.05, 1, 0.05);
const tableLeg1 = new THREE.Mesh(tableLegsGeometry, tableLegsMaterial)
// ...
tableLeg1.position.set(0.9, 0.5, -0.4)
// ...
```

Comment: Is this really the best practice way to approach this? By simple math? Is there no other way?
Eitherway your approach works so thank you very much!

Comment: @ArastoSahbaei What other way are you searching for? It is "your" geometry you've to define the shape and the location. Of course you can get the bounding box (AABB) of each part do some intersection tests and implement an algorithm which place the parts at its positions. But even then you would have to define the "rules" to place the parts of the geometry. To define a 3D object is almost math or you've to create (draw) the geometry with a tool like blender and to load it from a file.

Comment: Alternatively you could use ammo.js and let the board "fall" onto the legs ;-)